# MFMailComposer not working in the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I have an iPhone application where I am sending mails from 3 different buttons in three defferent viewcontrollers. I use MFMailComposerDelegates to achieve this in my viewcontrollers.

Everything is working fine in my simulator, but when I put it on the device none of the three are woking. The buttons will not providing anything, simply behaving like a button with no actions.

I implemented the delegate methods and everything and I am getting the desired result in the simulator.

Can anybody help me please...

Comment: Is mail configured in your device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before pushing the mail composer, call [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `canSendMail` to find whether you can be able to send mail.

You might not have configured mail in your device. You can configure that through **Settings**.

Comment: I did that but still cant.........was anything changed on ios5 regarding this..i am tested it my simulator 4.1.but my device is using ios5 .was it due to that?